# Venial sin and James 1:15

Tags: catholicism, sin

According to Catholic theology, venial sin ruins one's friendship with God, but it does not sever it completely so that the sinner merits Hell. However, James seems to say that **all** sin produces death. What is the official harmonization of James with the existence of venial sin?

Answer (score 1):

James 1:15

> Then desire conceives and brings forth sin, and when sin reaches maturity it gives birth to death.

You appear to have interpolated an "all" that is not, in fact, present in the verse.

Given that we also have  1 John 5:16-17

> If anyone sees his brother sinning, if the sin is not deadly, he should pray to God and he will give him life. This is only for those whose sin is not deadly. There is such a thing as deadly sin, about which I do not say that you should pray.  **All wrongdoing is sin, but there is sin that is not deadly.**

one concludes that just as not *all* sinful desires lead to actual sin, so too not *all* actual sins lead to death, because they do not all reach "maturity."

Comment: "Sin" generally speaking produces death. But venial sin, apparently, does not produce death. Unless venial sin is much more serious than we often think, in that while it may not merit Hell, it can alter one's relationship with God in a way that still requires salvation.

Comment: Many understand 1 John 5:16-17 to be in reference to the 'unpardonable sin' of Matthew 12:31-32, which is essentially rejection of the Holy Spirit's testimony to Jesus.  Otherwise, Catholics are prohibited, by 1 John, from praying for anyone who has committed mortal sin.

Comment: @MikeBorden there is much talk about death in relation to sin in the Bible.   Everywhere else, it clearly means any sin that leads to damnation.  The presumption is it means the same here.

Comment: @MikeBorden No, Catholics are not prohibited for "praying for anyone in mortal sin" because we don't prooftext -- that is, that's NOT how we read Scripture to inform doctrine. That interpretation would rule out everything else in Catholicism, so it cannot hold.

Comment: @AmatsukiLove the key in the verse cited is "maturity"; venial sin on its own doesn't  produce death but it does dispose one towards further sins, which can produce death. That is, repeated venial sins in one category make it easier to commit more and eventually mortal sins in that category

Comment: @eques John says there is sin that should be prayed for and sin that should not be prayed for....except for defining what those sins are there's no interpretation needed.  Is there sin that Catholics don't pray for?

Comment: @MikeBorden that would be an interesting separate question. My point was if you think you have found a single verse which disproves a Catholic doctrine, you haven't.

Comment: @eques Fair enough.